# Firebase InApp messaging test

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

How can we test in-app messages when a custom event occurs in Firebase
? my event show in DebugView firebase console but not show any message dialog in my application just show once when app start and when i trigger button test on device in Firebase console.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @ََAegir Unfortunately no

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to close then open the app?

Anyway, you chose to display "once per device for this campaign".
Because the message already "show once when app start", it will not show again. To trigger in-app message again, you need to uninstall and install the app.

Answer (score -1):

See popup Test on device: "Note: Test messages are triggered on app open."

You can't test message with event. It just show when you open app. You must publish your campaign, then message will appear.